# What is default variable access rights type in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

For example, I have some class A. And then I inherit another class from A.

```
@interface A : NSObject
{
    int _nonHiddenProp;

    @private 
        int _hiddenProp;
}
@property (nonatomic, assign) int property;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int nonHiddenProp;
@property (nonatomic, assign) int hiddenProp;
@end

@implementation A
- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _property = 1000;
    }

    return self;
}
@end


@interface B : A

@end

@implementation TestCapabilitiesChild

- (id)init
{
    if (self = [super init])
    {
        _nonHiddenProp = 1000;
        //I cannot call _property and _hiddenProperty
    }

    return self;
}
@end
```

But:

```
A *a = [[[A alloc] init] autorelease];
B *b = [[[B alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLog(@"BClassProperties %d %d %d", b.nonHiddenProp, b.property, b.hiddenProp);
```

Shows: BClassProperties 1000 1000 0

Why? If I cannot call variable _property in init of B it still is 1000?

Comment: it is protected by default

Answer (score 0):

You have explicitly declared two instance variables `_nonHiddenProp` and `_hiddenProp` of which  `_nonHiddenProp` has visibility to subclasses and `_hiddenProp` has visibility only to the class it is in.  You have also declared three properties: `property`, `nonHiddenProp` and `hiddenProp`.

The first thing to note is that properties are not variables.  Properties and instance variables are different things. A property is actually a pair of accessor methods, one to get its value and the other to set its value (the setter may be omitted for read only properties).  Note that by "its value" I mean the *property's value* not the value of any particular instance variable.  I might have mentioned this before but *properties and instance variables are not the same thing*.

As properties are really a pair of methods, the visibility rules for a property are the same as for methods, namely "all methods are public", therefore all properties are also public.

If you do not provide implementations for the property's two accessors and you do not explicitly synthesise the property, the compiler will automatically provide implementations.  This it does by:

- first inventing an instance variable name which is the same as the property name but with an underscore in front.
- if the instance variable doesn't already exist, it declares one with private visibility.
- create getter and setter to get/set the instance variable when the property is got/set.

You can't set the instance variable `_property` from within the subclass because the subclass does not have visibility of the instance variable.  The NSLog works because it is using the property, not the instance variable.

Answer (score -1):

You declared a property for the instance variable... this means, that a setter and getter was syntesized, which are methods... in Objective-C all methods are public (althrough you can "hide" them, or the compiler / IDE may prevent you from compiling)

But in reality and during runtime nothing prevents you from sending a message (calling a method) on that class

Comment: Not me that down voted you, but this is flat out false with respect to instance variables.